# Pre-biased transistor, what is infinite resistance pull-down resistor

Tags: transistors, resistors

I am trying to select a pre-biased transistor, and I noticed some of them have a what is listed as an infinite resistance base pull-down resistor.

I do not understand how or why an infinite resistance base pull-down resistor works, and if this has an advantage or disadvantage over lets say a normal 10K pull-down resistor.

Thank you for the help.

Screenshot from a datasheet:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just means that r2 is not installed. Actual infinite resistance is difficult to achieve ;-)

As to why do this instead of 10K? Perhaps there are applications where base current should be restricted but it is not desired to divide the input voltage in half?

Comment: Would this transistor be a good choice for an arduino if you say R2 is effectively not installed, can I assume the base is still held low even if something goes wrong with the microcontroller?

Comment: @aviatorken89, BJTs generally don't have the same issue as MOSFETs with the base/gate drifting around if its in a high impedance state. Because BJTs need non-zero base current to turn "on".

Comment: Hi Peter, as to why: I imagine this is part of a family of these transistors with R1 and R2 values each of 10K, 4K7, no-fit and so on. I've used 4K7/4K7 ones.